# Environment variable in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, gulp

I want to run a gulp test in Jenkins on my Windows7. The test succeeds when I'm running it in my cmd. So I use the command:

```
gulp test
```

But the gulp command isn't recognized when I'm adding gulp test in the windows batch command on Jenkins. I tried to make an environment variable for it. But it still fails. I have a prop.properties file with this input.

```
gulp=node node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
```

Than I use: Inject environment variables to the build process. I define the Properties File Path in my Jenkins. When I build the job i get this message:

```
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'C:/path/propfile.properties'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
```

but the variable isn't recognized by my windows batch command in Jenkins.

```
gulp is not recognized as internal or external command
```

Can someone explain me a method so I can use the gulp test command in my windows batch of Jenkins, instead of node node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js test?

Comment: you have 4 questions within the last week all asking the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406533/gulp-wont-work-in-jenkins, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408115/gulp-command-not-recognized-in-jenkins, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425571/command-not-recognized-after-running-job-in-jenkins, and this one. You don't accept answers, don't provide feedback if answers have helped you or not, and just keep asking the same thing over and over. Stick to a question, modify it if necessary. Don't spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the "Inject environment variables into the build process" 's section named "Property content" on windows you should add something like:

```
PATH=$WORKSPACE\node_modules\gulp\bin\;$PATH
```

one more thing is for running gulp.js as a node application, you should add NODE_PATH to the path

```
NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```